# Iterated models in R

Tags: r, loops, variables, iteration

Let's say that I wanted to create n random variables, then create n-1 models regressing each variable on a response.  I could do something like this:

```
x1 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x3 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x4 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x5 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x6 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x7 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
x8 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

model1 <- lm(y ~ x1)
model2 <- lm(y ~ x2)
model3 <- lm(y ~ x3)
model4 <- lm(y ~ x4)
model5 <- lm(y ~ x5)
model6 <- lm(y ~ x6)
model7 <- lm(y ~ x7)
model8 <- lm(y ~ x8)

summary model1
```

And so forth.  Obviously that's clunky, requires a lot of bookkeeping, and opens the door wide to substantial errors from typos.

I assume there's a more straightforward way to do this that doesn't have as much room for error?

Edit: Addressing the comments I apologize for the lack of clarity.  The specifics and data generating process here aren't particularly important to me. I just included toy data because I noticed that people typically include toy data when they have questions, and I thought it was convention here.

What I'm really looking for is a process for attacking this *sort* of problem.  It's commonplace in my line of work to have a large dataset and want to generate a large number of models comparing different pairs of variables.  I've been using the process described above where I write out every model by hand, or do some sort of concatenation of commands in excel and then cut-paste.  It just makes for really inefficient code, and I thought that there *had* to be a cleaner way to approach this in R, since this seems like the sort of thing people would frequently have to do.

Comment: what is your expected output? do you want the model summaries? do you want the models? do you want the random data? how much flexibility do you need in generating "random variables"? at this point, your question is quite unclear

Comment: Depends on how much data you want to create and run using regression, if it is relatively small, you can use for loop. For example, to create variables: 
`for (i in 1:8){
  assign(paste0("X", i, sep=""), rnorm(1000, 0, 1))
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `replicate` to draw the samples and plain `apply` over each sample to estimate the model:

```
X <- replicate(n = 99, expr = rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
apply(X, 2, function(z) { lm(y~z) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replicate

```
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

f = function(y){lm(y~rnorm(1000, 0, 1))}

models = replicate(10, f(y), simplify = FALSE)

summary(models[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
result_list <- lapply(1:8,function(i){
    summary(lm(y ~ get(paste0("x",i))))
})
```

This will give you a list with all the results.

If you don't need the input as single variables, you could put them into a matrix:

```
y <- rnorm(1000)
x_mat <- sapply(1:8,rnorm, n = 1000)
apply(x_mat,2,function(x){
    summary(lm(y ~ x))
})
```

This will again result in a list with the results

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this was helpful

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I don't (yet) have the reputation to upvote.